# How to reload a tableviewcontroller inside scrollview with pagination?

Tags: ios, scrollview, tableview, reload

I have several instances of Tableviewcontroller inside a Scrollview using NSMUTABLEARRAY with pagination. The basic usage of scrollview is to create instances of tableviewcontroller with different dates and display tableviews inside scrollable scrollview. Now what I am trying to achieve is to reload tableview with different data using a button at navigation?
Parent-view is Scrollview
for x=50, all the child-view is alloc and initialized null then updated with data. how when i do change a parameter. all the new pages created will make request according to the new parameter but those all loaded will stills how previous data.

Comment: Can you please post some code?

Comment: I used this http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/pagecontrol-example-in-iphone/ link to create the scrolling tableviews at pagenumbers. I need to reload them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting the answer for future results. Finally figured out after trying it hard.

```
   CGFloat width = scrollView.frame.size.width;
    //Getting the Current Page of ChildTableController inside scrollview
    NSInteger page = (scrollView.contentOffset.x + (0.5f * width)) / width;
    ChildTableController *child =[[ChildTableController alloc]initWithPageNumber:page];
    [child.tableView reloadData];
```

This is 
how I did it and it works.

- get the width of the scrollview that was created
- round the page int from the float
- instantiate the ChildTableController at page
- reload tableview inside instance

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last comment (without much more information), you could do something like this:

Call this method like so: `[self reloadTableViewsInScrollView:yourScrollView];`

```
- (void)reloadTableViewsInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    for (UITableViewController *sub in scrollView.subviews)
    {
        [sub.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Comment: Apologies, I have tableviewcontrollers using page

Comment: What is `page` exactly? What object type/class is it of?

Comment: Used - (void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page {
    if (page < 0) return;
    if (page >= kNumberOfPages) return;
 
    PageControlExampleViewControl *controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:page];
    if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null]) {
        controller = [[PageControlExampleViewControl alloc] initWithPageNumber:page];
        [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
        [controller release];
    } to create viewcontrollers at index of pagination in scrollview

Comment: I have the tableviewcontrollers all loading correctly according to page index. What I did was changed the parameter in the servicecall so the json response is different. I am trying to get the tableviewcontroller at page index which is given by  CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth); I do i exactly call the particular tableview and reload its data

Comment: I have the scrollview, and about thirty tableviewcontrollers inside it which is created dynamically using pagenumber and adding to it. - (void)reloadTableViewsInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    for (UITableView *sub in scrollView.subviews)
    {
        [sub reloadData];
    } should work as long as I can get the exact subview

Comment: I changed my answer, as I thought you didn't need that code

Comment: Great that you are up for helping me. I need to call the exact tableviewcontroller inside the scrollview, and reload data in in

Comment: it is reloading but all the tableviewcontrollers inside the pagination view are reloading (35 of them) so it is crashing at the moment. I will try to get the exact subview by indexing pagination and then reload. Thanks for the help should get me running